# Compute mean and variance, incrementally

Tags: c++, statistics, c++17

I have previously reviewed code that computes standard deviation using the mathematical formula **E(x²) - E(x)²**, and warned against the use of this formula because floating-point precision is severely compromised by subtracting almost-equal numbers.  I've started with the methods described in [Incremental calculation of weighted mean and variance](https://fanf2.user.srcf.net/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf) by Tony Finch.  However, I'm not an expert on numerical methods, so I'd like to know of any weaknesses in my version.

I got slightly carried away with generality, so I've included a version that works with complex numbers, and I've implemented a trailing-N-values rolling mean and variance.  I also present the unit-tests I used to write the classes - they are written for Google Test, but should be easy to convert if you prefer a different test runner.

As usual, I'd like feedback on any aspect that could be improved.  Although I wrote this only as an exercise for fun and practice, I do want to make *all* my code the best it can be.

```
#include <complex>
#include <deque>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>

struct container_underflow_error : public std::runtime_error
{
    explicit container_underflow_error(const char* desc = "empty container")
        : std::runtime_error(desc)
    {}
    explicit container_underflow_error(const std::string& desc)
        : std::runtime_error(desc)
    {}
};

namespace impl {
    static constexpr struct raw_tag {} raw_tag = {};
}

template<typename>
class SimpleStatsBag
{
    SimpleStatsBag() = delete;
};

template<typename T>
    requires std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN
class SimpleStatsBag<T>
{
    static constexpr auto nan = std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN();

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using variance_type = T;

private:
    std::size_t count = 0;
    value_type current_mean = 0;
    variance_type current_nvar = 0;     // count times the current variance

public:
    SimpleStatsBag() noexcept = default;
    SimpleStatsBag(std::initializer_list<T> items) noexcept
        : SimpleStatsBag{items.begin(), items.end()}
    {}
    template<typename It>       // InputIterator It
        requires requires(It i) { *++i; }
    SimpleStatsBag(It first, It last) noexcept
    {
        while (first != last)
            *this += *first++;
    }

    // tagged constructor (for internal use only)
    SimpleStatsBag(struct impl::raw_tag,
                   std::size_t size, value_type mean, variance_type nvar)
        : count(size), current_mean(mean), current_nvar(nvar)
    {}


    // Accessors for the statistical properties
    std::size_t size() const noexcept { return count; }

    value_type mean() const noexcept { return count ? current_mean : nan; }

    variance_type population_variance() const noexcept
    {
        return count ? current_nvar / count : nan;
    }
    variance_type sample_variance() const noexcept
    {
        return count > 1 ? population_variance() * count / (count - 1) : nan;
    }


    // Mutators

    // add and remove values
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(value_type value) noexcept
    {
        auto const old_mean = current_mean;
        current_mean += (value - current_mean) / ++count;
        current_nvar += (value - current_mean) * (value - old_mean);
        return *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(value_type value)
    {
        if (!count)
            throw container_underflow_error();
        auto const old_mean = current_mean;
        current_mean -= (value - current_mean) / --count;
        current_nvar -= (value - current_mean) * (value - old_mean);
        return *this;
    }

    // add/subtract bags
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(const SimpleStatsBag& other) const noexcept
    {
        auto new_count = count + other.count;
        auto new_mean = (current_mean * count + other.current_mean * other.count) / new_count;
        auto new_nvar = current_nvar + other.current_nvar
            + count * (current_mean - new_mean) * (current_mean - new_mean)
            + other.count * (other.current_mean - new_mean) * (other.current_mean - new_mean);

        return SimpleStatsBag(impl::raw_tag, new_count, new_mean, new_nvar);
    }

    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        return *this = *this + other;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(const SimpleStatsBag& other) const
    {
        auto new_count = count - other.count;
        auto new_mean = (current_mean * count - other.current_mean * other.count) / new_count;
        auto new_nvar = current_nvar - other.current_nvar
            + count * (current_mean - new_mean) * (current_mean - new_mean)
            - other.count * (other.current_mean - new_mean) * (other.current_mean - new_mean);

        return SimpleStatsBag(impl::raw_tag, new_count, new_mean, new_nvar);
    }

    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        return *this = *this - other;
    }
};

// specialize for complex numbers

template<typename T>
    requires std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN
class SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<T>>
{
    SimpleStatsBag<T> real = {};
    SimpleStatsBag<T> imag = {};

public:
    using value_type = std::complex<T>;
    using variance_type = T;

public:
    SimpleStatsBag() noexcept = default;
    template<typename It>       // InputIterator It
        requires requires(It i) { *++i; }
    SimpleStatsBag(It first, It last) noexcept
    {
        while (first != last)
            *this += (*first++);
    }
    SimpleStatsBag(const std::initializer_list<value_type> items) noexcept
        : SimpleStatsBag{items.begin(), items.end()}
    {}


    // Accessors for the statistical properties
    std::size_t size() const noexcept { return real.size(); }

    value_type mean() const noexcept { return {real.mean(), imag.mean()}; }

    variance_type population_variance() const noexcept {
        return real.population_variance() + imag.population_variance();
    }
    variance_type sample_variance() const noexcept
    {
        return real.sample_variance() + imag.sample_variance();
    }


    // add and remove values
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(value_type value) noexcept
    {
        real += value.real();
        imag += value.imag();
        return *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) -= value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(value_type value)
    {
        real -= value.real();
        imag -= value.imag();
        return *this;
    }

    // add and subtract bags
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(const SimpleStatsBag& other) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += other;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        real += other.real;
        imag += other.imag;
        return *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(const SimpleStatsBag& other) const
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) -= other;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        real -= other.real;
        imag -= other.imag;
        return *this;
    }
};


// <complex> doesn't provide these specializations of common_type.
// Technically, specializing these is undefined behaviour, but it is the
// least-pain way to mix and match complex and scalar values.
namespace std {
    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<std::complex<S>, T> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };
    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<S, std::complex<T>> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };
    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<std::complex<S>, std::complex<T>> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };
}

// deduction guide - promote to at least double
template<typename... T> SimpleStatsBag(T...)
    -> SimpleStatsBag<typename std::common_type_t<T..., double>>;


// Rolling statitistics
template<typename T = double>
class RollingStatsBag : SimpleStatsBag<T>
{
    std::size_t capacity;
    std::deque<T> recent = {};

public:
    RollingStatsBag(std::size_t capacity)
        : capacity{capacity}
    {}

    using typename SimpleStatsBag<T>::value_type;

    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::size;
    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::mean;
    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::population_variance;
    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::sample_variance;

    // add value
    RollingStatsBag operator+(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return RollingStatsBag(*this) += value;
    }
    RollingStatsBag& operator+=(value_type value) noexcept
    {
        recent.push_back(value);
        SimpleStatsBag<T>::operator+=(value);
        if (size() > capacity) {
            SimpleStatsBag<T>::operator-=(recent.front());
            recent.pop_front();
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

```
// Test suite

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <cmath>                // std::isnan

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, empty)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), double>);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, b.size());
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.mean()));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.population_variance()));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.sample_variance()));
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, one_element)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100};
    EXPECT_EQ(1, b.size());
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
    EXPECT_EQ(0, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.sample_variance()));
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, single_precision)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100.f};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), double>);
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, long_double)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100.L};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), long double>);
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, complex)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{std::complex{100.f, -100.f}};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), std::complex<double>>);
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100, b.mean().real());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(-100, b.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.sample_variance()));
}



TEST(SimpleStatsBag, two_double)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{0, 200};
    EXPECT_EQ(2, b.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100, b.mean());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(10000, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(20000, b.sample_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, two_complex)
{
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<double>> b{ {100, -100}, {100, 100} };
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100, b.mean().real());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(10000, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(20000, b.sample_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, mixed_complex)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{std::complex{100.f, -100.f}, std::complex{100.l, -100.l}};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), std::complex<long double>>);
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100.l, b.mean().real());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(-100.l, b.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.sample_variance());
}


TEST(SimpleStatsBag, remove)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{0, 200, 4000};
    b -= 4000;
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
    EXPECT_EQ(10000, b.population_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, remove_all)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100};
    b -= 100;
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.mean()));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.population_variance()));
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, remove_more)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{};
    ASSERT_THROW(b -= 100, std::runtime_error);
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, add_bags)
{
    SimpleStatsBag a{100, 1000};
    SimpleStatsBag b{200, 300};
    auto c = a + b;
    SimpleStatsBag d{100, 200, 300, 1000};
    EXPECT_EQ(d.size(), c.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(d.mean(), c.mean());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(d.population_variance(), c.population_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, subtract_bags)
{
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<float>> a{100, 200, 300, 1000};
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<float>> b{200, 300};
    auto c = a - b;
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<float>> d{100, 1000};
    EXPECT_EQ(d.size(), c.size());
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(d.mean().real(), c.mean().real());
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(d.mean().imag(), c.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(d.population_variance(), c.population_variance());
}


TEST(RollingStatsBag, real)
{
    RollingStatsBag a{3};
    a += 10;
    a += 20;
    a += 30;
    EXPECT_EQ(3, a.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(20, a.mean());
    a += 40;
    EXPECT_EQ(3, a.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(30, a.mean());
}


TEST(RollingStatsBag, complex)
{
    RollingStatsBag<std::complex<double>> a{2};
    a += 0;
    a += {0, -100};
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(2500, a.population_variance());
    a += {0, -100};
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(1, 1+a.population_variance());
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The loop

  ```
  while (first != last)
      *this += *first++;
  ```

  is `std::accumulate`.
- `SimpleStatsBag operator-` has a typo. It says `return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += value;`. You surely meant `-=`.

  That said, I don't see the statistical meaning of the removal methods.
- It looks strange that `SimpleStatBag operator+=(const SimpleStatsBag& other)` is implemented in terms of `operator+`. A canonical implementation is other way around (like you did for `SimpleStatBag operator+(value_type value)`. At the very list it is expected that `operator+=` should not create intermediate objects.
- `requires requires`?
- I honestly don't see any reason to spell out a specialization for `complex`.
- Please forgive a short lecture by a (used to be) numerical expert.

  1. A danger of subtracting almost-equal values was known since at least 19th century, and it has nothing to do with the floating point. It may increase the *relative error* dramatically.

     A numeric example: any scientific measurement is imprecise, and the value measured must be accompanied by the margin of error. For example you've measured `a` as \$10000000 \pm 1\$ - a pretty good precision; you've also measure `b` as  \$ 9999999 \pm 1\$ - also very good. Now `a-b` is \$1 \pm 2\$. Bummer. The relative error is 200%. Notice that no floating point was involved. As a side note, the imprecision of floating point is usually negligible to the imprecision of data.

     PS: `current_mean += (value - current_mean) / ++count;` makes me wonder whether your code address the issue you are trying to solve.
  2. The hazard inherent to floating point has another nature. It manifests in adding (or subtracting) values of *wildly different* magnitudes. To add two floating point numbers you need to equalize their exponents, and add mantissas. Now while increasing the exponent of the least number, you must shift its mantissa right, therefore losing significant digits.

     Another numeric example. Imagine that we have only 2 digits of mantissa. Now try to compute `1.0e1 + 1.0e-1`. After equalization we have `1.0e1 + 0.01e1`. Since mantissa has only 2 digits, the second term degenerates to `0`(*), and the result is `1.0e1`. And if we do it in the loop, then no matter how long the loop is, the result would remain `1.0e1`.

     The only way to counter this is to sort the values by magnitude, and work from smaller to larger ones.

     <sub>(*) The degeneration is known as floating point underflow, and can be detected by hardware, but in less extreme cases you still may lose many significant digits unnoticed.</sub>

Comment: `requires requires(/*param list*/) { /* requirements */ }` is legit C++20 concepts syntax for an ad-hoc requirement. It's the same idea as `noexcept(noexcept(/* expression */))`.

Comment: @indi Good to know, thank you. The question however was tagged with C++17, and my compiler barfed.

Comment: It is also legit C++17 (and C++14) with the Concepts TS. You might have to use a flag with your compiler to enable it, depending on your compiler.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention the dependence on Concepts TS - I should have said that if it's not available to you, you can just remove the `requires` specification.  (I did want to use the new concise form, as commented, but my compiler's Standard Library doesn't yet define the named concept I needed).

Comment: Can you explain, "*I honestly don't see any reason to spell out a specialization for `complex`*"?  I couldn't see another way to make my code work for complex numbers.  If you have a simpler suggestion, I'd love to see it.  Thanks.

Comment: And thanks for the recommendation to implement `+` in terms of `+=` consistently.  I thought that would be more complex, but it completely removes the need for the tagged constructor, and is much simpler that way around.

Comment: @vnp - how about using a poor-man HDR histogram instead of the incremental mean/avg (use the exponent and few MSBs of the `double` to address buckets)? It has a bit of a memory footprint but otherwise should not be subject to the floating point math pitfalls you explained in your answer.

Comment: *"The only way to counter this is to sort the values by magnitude, and work from smaller to larger ones."* This is also not correct, if you add the same value over and over, at some point the sum will be much larger than that value, and you have the same issue. Better is to use [pairwise summation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256328/pairwise-summation), or maybe both combined.

Comment: In this case, note that if subtraction nearly cancels, then it's because the value begin inserted is very close to the running mean, and it results in a near-zero adjustment, as desired.  I have faith that the paper I referenced avoids both the floating-point hazards you mention.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a way to get a working `common_type<>` implementation for `std::complex` without defining specializations in `std` (which is UB) and without re-implementing most of `std::common_type<>` for myself (which is messy):

```
namespace my {
    template<typename... T>
    struct common_type : public std::common_type<T...> {};

    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<std::complex<S>, T> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };
    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<S, std::complex<T>> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };
    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<std::complex<S>, std::complex<T>> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };

    template<typename... T>
    using common_type_t = typename common_type<T...>::type;
}

// deduction guide - promote to at least double
template<typename... T> SimpleStatsBag(T...)
    -> SimpleStatsBag<typename my::common_type_t<T..., double>>;
```

The trick I missed was to publicly *inherit* from `std::common_type<>` rather than trying to bring it in with `using`.

Answer (score 1):

Modified code, incorporating advice from answers:

```
#include <complex>
#include <deque>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>

struct container_underflow_error : public std::runtime_error
{
    explicit container_underflow_error(const char* desc = "empty container")
        : std::runtime_error(desc)
    {}
    explicit container_underflow_error(const std::string& desc)
        : std::runtime_error(desc)
    {}
};

template<typename>
class SimpleStatsBag
{
    SimpleStatsBag() = delete;
};

template<typename T>
    requires std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN
class SimpleStatsBag<T>
{
    static constexpr auto nan = std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN();

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using variance_type = T;

private:
    std::size_t count = 0;
    value_type current_mean = 0;
    variance_type current_nvar = 0;     // count times the current variance

public:
    SimpleStatsBag() noexcept = default;
    SimpleStatsBag(std::initializer_list<T> items) noexcept
        : SimpleStatsBag{items.begin(), items.end()}
    {}
    template<typename It>       // InputIterator It
        requires requires(It i) { *++i; }
    SimpleStatsBag(It first, It last) noexcept
    {
        *this = std::accumulate(first, last, SimpleStatsBag());
    }


    // Accessors for the statistical properties
    std::size_t size() const noexcept { return count; }

    value_type mean() const noexcept { return count ? current_mean : nan; }

    variance_type population_variance() const noexcept
    {
        return count ? current_nvar / count : nan;
    }
    variance_type sample_variance() const noexcept
    {
        return count > 1 ? population_variance() * count / (count - 1) : nan;
    }


    // Mutators

    // add and remove values
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(value_type value) noexcept
    {
        auto const old_mean = current_mean;
        current_mean += (value - current_mean) / ++count;
        current_nvar += (value - current_mean) * (value - old_mean);
        return *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) -= value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(value_type value)
    {
        if (!count)
            throw container_underflow_error();
        auto const old_mean = current_mean;
        current_mean -= (value - current_mean) / --count;
        current_nvar -= (value - current_mean) * (value - old_mean);
        return *this;
    }

    // add/subtract bags
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(SimpleStatsBag other) const noexcept
    {
        return other += *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        auto const new_count = count + other.count;
        auto const new_mean = (current_mean * count + other.current_mean * other.count) / new_count;

        current_nvar += other.current_nvar
            + count * (current_mean - new_mean) * (current_mean - new_mean)
            + other.count * (other.current_mean - new_mean) * (other.current_mean - new_mean);

        count = new_count;
        current_mean = new_mean;
        return *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(const SimpleStatsBag& other) const
    {
        return other -= *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        auto const new_count = count - other.count;
        auto const new_mean = (current_mean * count - other.current_mean * other.count) / new_count;
        current_nvar -= other.current_nvar
            - count * (current_mean - new_mean) * (current_mean - new_mean)
            + other.count * (other.current_mean - new_mean) * (other.current_mean - new_mean);

        count = new_count;
        current_mean = new_mean;
        return *this;
    }
};

// specialize for complex numbers

template<typename T>
    requires std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN
class SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<T>>
{
    SimpleStatsBag<T> real = {};
    SimpleStatsBag<T> imag = {};

public:
    using value_type = std::complex<T>;
    using variance_type = T;

public:
    SimpleStatsBag() noexcept = default;
    template<typename It>       // InputIterator It
        requires requires(It i) { *++i; }
    SimpleStatsBag(It first, It last) noexcept
    {
        while (first != last)
            *this += (*first++);
    }
    SimpleStatsBag(const std::initializer_list<value_type> items) noexcept
        : SimpleStatsBag{items.begin(), items.end()}
    {}


    // Accessors for the statistical properties
    std::size_t size() const noexcept { return real.size(); }

    value_type mean() const noexcept { return {real.mean(), imag.mean()}; }

    variance_type population_variance() const noexcept {
        return real.population_variance() + imag.population_variance();
    }
    variance_type sample_variance() const noexcept
    {
        return real.sample_variance() + imag.sample_variance();
    }


    // add and remove values
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(value_type value) noexcept
    {
        real += value.real();
        imag += value.imag();
        return *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) -= value;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(value_type value)
    {
        real -= value.real();
        imag -= value.imag();
        return *this;
    }

    // add and subtract bags
    SimpleStatsBag operator+(const SimpleStatsBag& other) const noexcept
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) += other;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator+=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        real += other.real;
        imag += other.imag;
        return *this;
    }

    SimpleStatsBag operator-(const SimpleStatsBag& other) const
    {
        return SimpleStatsBag(*this) -= other;
    }
    SimpleStatsBag& operator-=(const SimpleStatsBag& other) noexcept
    {
        real -= other.real;
        imag -= other.imag;
        return *this;
    }
};

namespace util {
    template<typename... T>
    struct common_type : public std::common_type<T...> {};

    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<std::complex<S>, T> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };
    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<S, std::complex<T>> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };
    template<typename S, typename T>
    struct common_type<std::complex<S>, std::complex<T>> {
        using type = std::complex<typename std::common_type_t<S, T>>;
    };

    template<typename... T>
    using common_type_t = typename common_type<T...>::type;
}

// deduction guide - promote to at least double
template<typename... T> SimpleStatsBag(T...)
    -> SimpleStatsBag<typename util::common_type_t<T..., double>>;


// Rolling statitistics
template<typename T = double>
class RollingStatsBag : SimpleStatsBag<T>
{
    std::size_t capacity;
    std::deque<T> recent = {};

public:
    RollingStatsBag(std::size_t capacity)
        : capacity{capacity}
    {}

    using typename SimpleStatsBag<T>::value_type;

    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::size;
    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::mean;
    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::population_variance;
    using SimpleStatsBag<T>::sample_variance;

    // add value
    RollingStatsBag operator+(value_type value) const noexcept
    {
        return RollingStatsBag(*this) += value;
    }
    RollingStatsBag& operator+=(value_type value) noexcept
    {
        recent.push_back(value);
        SimpleStatsBag<T>::operator+=(value);
        if (size() > capacity) {
            SimpleStatsBag<T>::operator-=(recent.front());
            recent.pop_front();
        }
        return *this;
    }
};


// Test suite

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <cmath>                // std::isnan

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, empty)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), double>);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, b.size());
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.mean()));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.population_variance()));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.sample_variance()));
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, one_element)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100};
    EXPECT_EQ(1, b.size());
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
    EXPECT_EQ(0, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.sample_variance()));
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, single_precision)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100.f};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), double>);
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, long_double)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100.L};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), long double>);
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, complex)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{std::complex{100.f, -100.f}};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), std::complex<double>>);
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100, b.mean().real());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(-100, b.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.sample_variance()));
}



TEST(SimpleStatsBag, two_double)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{0, 200};
    EXPECT_EQ(2, b.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100, b.mean());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(10000, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(20000, b.sample_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, two_complex)
{
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<double>> b{ {100, -100}, {100, 100} };
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100, b.mean().real());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(10000, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(20000, b.sample_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, mixed_complex)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{std::complex{100.f, -100.f}, std::complex{100.l, -100.l}};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.mean()), std::complex<long double>>);
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(100.l, b.mean().real());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(-100.l, b.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.population_variance());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(0, b.sample_variance());
}


TEST(SimpleStatsBag, remove)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{0, 200, 4000};
    b -= 4000;
    EXPECT_EQ(100, b.mean());
    EXPECT_EQ(10000, b.population_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, remove_all)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{100};
    b -= 100;
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.mean()));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(b.population_variance()));
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, remove_more)
{
    SimpleStatsBag b{};
    ASSERT_THROW(b -= 100, std::runtime_error);
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, add_bags)
{
    SimpleStatsBag a{100, 1000};
    SimpleStatsBag b{200, 300};
    auto c = a + b;
    SimpleStatsBag d{100, 200, 300, 1000};
    EXPECT_EQ(d.size(), c.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(d.mean(), c.mean());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(d.population_variance(), c.population_variance());
}

TEST(SimpleStatsBag, subtract_bags)
{
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<float>> a{100, 200, 300, 1000};
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<float>> b{200, 300};
    auto c = a - b;
    SimpleStatsBag<std::complex<float>> d{100, 1000};
    EXPECT_EQ(d.size(), c.size());
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(d.mean().real(), c.mean().real());
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(d.mean().imag(), c.mean().imag());
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(d.population_variance(), c.population_variance());
}


TEST(RollingStatsBag, real)
{
    RollingStatsBag a{3};
    a += 10;
    a += 20;
    a += 30;
    EXPECT_EQ(3, a.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(20, a.mean());
    a += 40;
    EXPECT_EQ(3, a.size());
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(30, a.mean());
}


TEST(RollingStatsBag, complex)
{
    RollingStatsBag<std::complex<double>> a{2};
    a += 0;
    a += {0, -100};
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(2500, a.population_variance());
    a += {0, -100};
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(1, 1+a.population_variance());
}
```